# WAMP working remotely but port is removed in Wordpress

Tags: port-forwarding, wamp

I have set up WAMP so that I can view this on another computer on the LAN on 192.168.1.73:8081 (i.e. a custom port) via `httpd.conf`

```
Listen 192.168.1.73:8081
Listen 192.168.1.73:80
```

then

```
ServerName 192.168.1.73:8081
```

I can see the WAMP server grey page correctly. When I view my Wordpress project, it loads parts of the site, but the CSS does not load. Looking at the source, it's referring to `http://localhost/wp-content/...` instead (I would imagine) of `http://192.168.1.73:8081/wp-content/...`

Comment: You might also try asking this on [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The path used here is generally defined in your WordPress settings. Look in your WordPress configuration for incidences of `localhost` and try replacing those.

I wouldn't use the IP address and port as the Apache `ServerName`, but I doubt that's affecting WordPress.